# nil coalescing: Using optional types as default value in Swift

Tags: swift, option-type, null-coalescing

I have this:

```
let queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)

        dispatch_async(queue, {
            if let data = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(self.buildRequestForVenueLocation(location, identifier), returningResponse: &response, error: &error) {
                let responseDictionary: AnyObject? = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .allZeros, error:&error) ?? error?.localizedDescription
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    completion(venues: responseDictionary, error: error)
                })
            } else {
                println("There was a problem with the request...")
            }
        })
```

My question is regarding this line in particular:

```
let responseDictionary: AnyObject? = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .allZeros, error:&error) ?? error?.localizedDescription
```

Is this correct usage of `nil coalescing`?

According to Apple's documentation this is the equvivalent:

```
a != nil ? a! : b
```

If a is nil, b is returned, but does is matter if the b is an optional type?

**EDIT**

In case anyone was wondering, here's what it looks like when I call the function:

```
v.performVenueLocationRequest(l.location, identifier: "4d4b7105d754a06374d81259") {
        if let result = $0 as? [String: AnyObject] ?? $1 {
            println(result)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what you mean by "matter". It will work. It just might not be what you want - if `b` is optional, then the result will also be optional i.e. even if `a` has a value it still won't be unwrapped:

```
let a: Int? = 2
let b: Int? = 3
let c = i ?? j
// c is {Some 2}
```

versus:

```
let i: Int? = nil
let j: Int? = 3
let k = i ?? j
// k is {Some 3}
```

See [this article](http://airspeedvelocity.net/2014/08/12/yo-dawg/) for probably more than you want to know about why, but in short: the result must be fixed as a specific type at compile time regardless of what the values of `a` and `b` are at runtime. Since `b` is an optional, `a!` is implicitly wrapped in an optional to make the two types compatible.  Put it this way – if the result were not optional, and `b` were `nil`, what would the result be?

Bear in mind you can chain `??` so you could put a third value on the end that isn't optional that would make the result non-optional.

Comment: Got it, thanks! In my case though - the dictionary that is passed to the closure the takes two optional arguments anyway, then I unwrap in the actual function call

Answer (score 0):

This is nil coalescing.

If b is not optional : 
 `a ?? b` will return unwrapped a, if a is not nil. If a is nil, it will return b.

If b is non optional : 
 `a ?? b` will return a, if a is not nil. If a is nil, it will return b.

This code will work.
But since you are capturing the error separately anyway, I would recommend leaving responseDictionary as nil instead of assigning it to `error.localDescription`(if it fails). It's just better design. Like below.

```
let responseDictionary: AnyObject? = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .allZeros, error:&error)
```

Comment: "This is nil coalescing. a ?? b will return unwrapped a, if a is not nil. If a is nil, it will return b.” Not if `b` is optional it won’t...

Comment: oh thanks. I didn't know what will happen if b is optional. but makes sense.